# Reinitializing jScroll after AJAX call? (Still loading old href after AJAX load)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I'm paginating search results returned from an AJAX call with [jScroll](http://jscroll.com/):

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    $.get('/search', {search : search}, function(results) {
        $('.scroll-table').html(results);
        $('.scroll-table').jscroll();
    });
});
```

After making a new search, when I scroll to the bottom, jScroll loads the content of the last href for the old search.

So if my old _nextHref was `/search?query=A&page=3` and I enter B in the search field, instead of loading `/search?query=B&page=2` from the new href, it will load `/search?query=A&page=3` from the old href.

Apparently calling jscroll() from the ajax success function won't reconstruct it and _nextHref stays set to its old value. I tried destroying it before loading it, but it will keep it fom loading altogether:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var search = $(this).val();

    $('.scroll-table').jscroll.destroy();

    $.get('/search', {search : search}, function(results) {
        $('.scroll-table').html(results);
        $('.scroll-table').jscroll();  /* now jScroll won't load at all */
    });
});
```

Can you please give me an example how to reinitialize jScroll so it loads the new href?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a temporary solution by commenting out the following line:

```
// if (data && data.initialized) return;
```

This caused a further problem.. If the result list fits a single page (no pagination needed so there is no href on the first page, "Loading..." is displayed on the bottom of the list, because jScroll wanted to `GET "/undefined"` from the server. Here is how i fixed it:

```
// Initialization
if (_nextHref != 'undefined') {
    $e.data('jscroll', $.extend({}, _data, {initialized: true, waiting: false, nextHref: _nextHref}));
    _wrapInnerContent();
    _preloadImage();
    _setBindings();
} else {
    _debug('warn', 'jScroll: nextSelector not found - destroying');
    _destroy();
    return false;
}
```

I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but now it works with AJAX calls as I expect it to work. If anyone knows of a proper way to reinitialize the plugin, please share it with us.

**UPDATE:** I created a [proper fork](https://github.com/orszaczky/jscroll) of jScroll allowing it to be reinitialized on each AJAX load, preventing it from loading the old href, using:

```
$('.scroll').jscroll({
    refresh: true
});
```

Hopefully this functionality gets merged in the main version.

Comment: I'm glad if u found it useful :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to patch jScroll, you can clear the jScroll data in your `load` (or `get`) callback:

```
var pane = $('#myInfiniteScroll');
pane.load(url, function() {
        pane.data('jscroll', null);
        pane.jscroll({
                    nextSelector: "link[rel='next']",
                    autoTrigger: true,
                  });
    });
```

When you call the `jscroll` function, pass the same parameters as when you first initialized it (in this example, I defined two configuration parameters, but use what you need.). Better yet, factor that out into its own function so you don't end up duplicating code.

Comment: My exact scenario wasn't the same. On page load I was lazy-loading some results using AJAX after the dom was ready and then binding the jScroll plugin. It worked great except when the user added or changed filters I needed a way to start "clean", loading the first page and re-binding the jScroll. By using the .data('jscroll',null) I was able to successfully do that.

Comment: I have a pretty different scenario myself : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035630/change-option-and-reinitialize.