# Change option and reinitialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `jscroll` as an infinite scroll pager.

```
$j('.frontpage').jscroll({
    loadingHtml: '<div style="text-align: center;"><img width="50" src="ring-alt-1.gif" alt="Loading" /></div>',
    padding: 20,
    nextSelector: 'div.next a',
    contentSelector: '.latest-container',
    autoTrigger: true,
    autoTriggerUntil: 1
});
```

This is a pretty neat plugin and it uses the must-have for my project `autoTriggerUntil`.
Using that method you can limit the times that the content loads automatic and show the pagination's "next" button.

What I am trying to achieve is this.

1. Load the first set of posts (actually the 2nd page) with infinite. (DONE)
2. After the 2nd page, show a "Load All" button. (DONE)
3. Both 1 and 2 work but what I am trying to do is this: After clicking the "Load All" on page 2, I want to destroy the limiter and get back to an infinite view until the end.

I basically need to reinitialize this somehow. I have been messing with intervals and other bad practices the last couple of hours with no results.

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584065/reinitializing-jscroll-after-ajax-call-still-loading-old-href-after-ajax-load  and https://github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll/issues/22 might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging I came out with this solution:-

first, you need to add a callback function like this:-

```
$('.frontpage').jscroll({
    //your existing settings ,
    callback: function() {
      if ($('div.next a').is(":visible")) {
         $('.frontpage').jscroll.destroy();
         $('div.next a').off('click');
       }
    }
});
```

Second Add **onclick** attribute to the load All **a** tag (only in the page where the load all **a** tag is **visible**)

```
onclick="loadAllClick(event);"
```

and the handler function should be like this:-

```
  <script>
      var loadAllClick = function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $('.frontpage').jscroll( //your settings 
                               );
          }
  </script>
```

and [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/URpjWqxr2lCJLm4zWeHy?p=preview) is a fully working plunker sample
Hope this answers your  question

Comment: Thank you ! It seems to be working in your example but not on the website. This issue is driving me crazy. Thank you though, I will fiddle with it a bit.

Comment: ok fiddle a bit and try to simulate the example and i am happy to be of any help

Comment: Thank you again ! You can see this live at mygadgeto.com . It receives the event and ... nothing.

Comment: i sew your code i found the function like this

$j('.frontpage').jscroll({
      loadingHtml: '<div style="text-align: center;"><img width="50" src="https://mygadgeto.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ring-alt-1.gif" alt="Loading" /></div>',
      padding: 20,
      nextSelector: '.next',
      contentSelector: '.category-prv',
      autoTrigger: true
  });

where is the **call back** as in the answer above and the 
**autoTriggerUntil: 1**

Comment: Removed it in case of it conflicting with the main page but nothing :/

Comment: what conflict you are talking about

Comment: This is a function used on another page for which I am going to change the class. I now have an identical setup to yours but still nothing.

Comment: remove the setting **autoTriggerUntil:0**

Comment: Done, still nothing. It's weird since your example is perfect in every way

Comment: the very weird thing is it worked after I applied your code exactly it worked. have a look again on the sample after updated.

Comment: Fixed it ! It seems like the frontpage class was nowhere to be found on the second page. Thank you very much !

Comment: happy to know :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$(el).off()` method and the plugin's `callback` option.

Tested on the plugin page http://jscroll.com/.

It can look something like this:

```
var counter = 0;
function scrollerCallback(){
  counter++;
  if(counter<2){return;}
    var el = $j('div.next a'); //Your 'next' selector
    el.off()
    el.on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // we don't want the browser to go to redirect
      // Add your code to show the rest of the comments here.
  });
}
```

And then call bind the same way but add callback:

```
$j('.frontpage').jscroll({
    loadingHtml: '<div style="text-align: center;"><img width="50" src="ring-alt-1.gif" alt="Loading" /></div>',
    ...
    callback:scrollerCallback,
    autoTriggerUntil: 1
});
```

Comment: Hello and thank you ! I tried to reinitiate it, by adding the new settings (with autotriggeruntil set to 0) after the `e.preventDefault();` but it persists on showing the "Load All", and in that state it freezes. 
You can take a look at mygadgeto.com

Comment: The code is commented in custom_js you can uncomment it to fiddle with it.

Answer (score 1):

In your CallBack function, try using this:

```
var counter = 0;
function scrollerCallback(){
  counter++;
  if(counter<2){return;}
    var el = $j(document).find('div.next a');
    el.on('click',function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("This call gets executed!");

      $j('.frontpage').jscroll({
        autoTrigger: false,
        autoTriggerUntil: false
      });

  });
}
```

What happens when you do this? I guess you have to modify the library itself for this to work, but I am not quite sure yet ...

Comment: Thank you ! Unfortunately this solution does not work.